# What is the most efficient to store variable sized groups of matrices?

Tags: python, numpy

If this has been asked and answered before, I will remove it.

I'd like to initialize a collection of `m x m` matrices in different, distinct groups. Given the parameter `n`, the first group consists of `n-1` matrices, the second one of `n-2` and so on. Preferrably, I'd like the matrices to be initialized with each column being an array of type `np.linspace(0,1,m)`. I've considered initializing a 4D numpy array, however, only half of the matrices will be needed then. Is storing the matrices in a list a better option?

```
import numpy as np
n=2
m=2
M = np.zeros([n,n,m,m])
for i in range(0,n):
   for j in range(i,n): 
      for k in range(0, m):
         M[i,j,:,k] = np.linspace(0,1,m)
```

EDIT1: It is not so important how the elements of the matrices are initialized.

EDIT2: It is not true that only half of the matrices will be needed in the 4D array, since each row of matrices would start on the diagonal to get the correct number of matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to show your code produces.  Most of us can't simply read the code and imagine what what exactly is happening.

```
     ...: n=2
     ...: m=2
     ...: M = np.zeros([n,n,m,m])
     ...: for i in range(0,n):
     ...:    for j in range(i,n):
     ...:       for k in range(0, m):
     ...:          M[i,j,:,k] = np.linspace(0,1,m)
     ...: 
In [388]: M
Out[388]: 
array([[[[0., 0.],
         [1., 1.]],

        [[0., 0.],
         [1., 1.]]],


       [[[0., 0.],
         [0., 0.]],

        [[0., 0.],
         [1., 1.]]]])
```

I get the same thing by replacing the `k` loop with:

```
      M[i,j,:,:] = np.linspace(0,1,m)[:,None]
```

### edit - valid for `j in range(0,n)`, not `range(i,n)`:

or all loops with

```
M[...] = np.linspace(0,1,m)[:,None]
```

or even

```
M = np.tile(np.linspace(0,1,m).reshape(1,1,m,1), (n,n,1,m))
```

or

```
M = np.broadcast_to(np.linspace(0,1,m)[:,None], (n,n,m,m))
```

### correction

We could use `np.triu_indices` to assign the `linspace` array to the upper triangle of the (n,n) dimensions:

```
In [421]: M = np.zeros([n,n,m,m])
In [422]: M[np.triu_indices(n)] = np.linspace(0,1,m)[:,None]
In [423]: M
Out[423]: 
array([[[[0., 0.],
         [1., 1.]],

        [[0., 0.],
         [1., 1.]]],


       [[[0., 0.],
         [0., 0.]],

        [[0., 0.],
         [1., 1.]]]])
```

where:

```
In [425]: np.triu_indices(n)
Out[425]: (array([0, 0, 1]), array([0, 1, 1]))
```

Comment: Thanks for showing the output. I should have included it. But it produces an upper triangular matrix of matrices, right? The matrix with zeros will not be used, so that half the matrices won’t be used is not entirely true. However, there will be a couple of matrices with zeros once n grows...

Comment: I don't see an upper triangular.  As my simplifications show you are generating a 1d array and expanding it to 4d.

Comment: And the expanded 4d array is an upper triangular array, right? That is, all matrices below the diagonal are matrices with all elements being zero.

Comment: I missed the `i` in `for j in range(i,n):` (and the extra 0s in the 3rd block).  So eliminating the `k` loop is still relevant, but not the rest of my answer.  That said, there is a set of `np.tri...` functions that create or index upper or lower triangular arrays.  In `numpy` we usually don't try to save space with such arrays, instead just set the values to 0.  Try to save space or store `ragged` arrays is computationally slow in `numpy`.